# Why docker container status in hyper-v virtual machine not correct?

Tags: docker, hyper-v

**The whole story:**

Usually I use `docker ps` to check container status to see if any restart of container.

Recently, I setup one hyper-v machine in windows10, also install ubuntu18.04 in this hyper-v machine. Meanwhile I install docker in this ubuntu18.04.

I new some containers in this ubuntu18.04, then I directly shutdown the windows10 pc before go to sleep.

Later some day, when I remember this thing again I start the win10 pc, ssh to this virutual machine & did next:

```
cake@cake:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                  NAMES
0ac07c24c537  wordpress   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago     Up 5 days     0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   gg_wordpress_1
3c47669c927f  mysql:5.7   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago     Up 5 days     3306/tcp, 33060/tcp    gg_db_1
```

**Problem:**

You could see the containers created 5 days ago which is ok, but the `STATUS` shown the containers are already up for 5 days.

I'm sure I have close the windows10 pc during this 5 days, meanwhile after find above thing I also reshutdown win10 to check if `8080` of one container service could be accessed?(The result is sure that it could not be accessed). Then I restart the win10 pc, execute `docker ps` again, I suppose the `STATUS` is something like `1 second ago`, but still `5 days ago`.

**NOTE:** don't suggest `docker for windows with MobyLinuxVM in hyperv`, I just want to know why my issue happen.

**UPDATE:**

As I said in comments:

> If execute `uptime` in bash, it will show : `20:57:41 up 1 day, 2:23, 1 user, load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00`

I there is one situation could explain this: pause the hyper-v. This will make the VM pause, meanwhile `uptime` stop to count, but `docker ps` still not stop to count, it just count the real time. Not sure why.

So, my situation could be next:

a) 5 days ago, I start the containers.

b) 4 days ago, I pause the VM (Not sure, maybe other operation similar)

c) Just now, for some operation not sure, the VM unpaused.

d) Then, I could with `uptime` see the VM start for 1 day; but with `docker ps` still see the container up for 5 days.

e) During these five days, I certainly not shutdown the VM; I just not only once shutdown windows10 physical machine. But it seems not affect the time counter for virtual linux machine.

So, it seems directly shutdown win10 machine not affect time counter of hyper-v linux virtual machine.

Another word: if by pass VM pause, if we directly shutdown win10. Then, although the service in hyper-v VM also interrupte, but when win10 & hyper-v VM linux back, the VM just behave like never stop, the `uptime` also counter during the stop period of hyper-v VM. Seems now narrow down my issue to this hyper-v behavior.

Anyone could explain this hyper-v behavior?

Comment: If you never stopped the containers, and never stopped the VM, then it's not really surprising to me that Docker would conclude the container has been running as long as it's existed.

Comment: @DavidMaze In physical machine, if host crash, the docker surely know it as dockerd also crashed. In VM, the windows10 close, then surely VM crash, the dockerd in VM also crash, what's the difference of the two above?

Comment: Meanwhile, next is the VM output with `uptime` : `20:57:41 up 1 day,  2:23,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00`

Comment: I am not convinced the VM will restart in the scenario you describe.  And it's much easier for any program to conclude time running is (now - last start time) than to try to actually measure the time the system is up.  Does this have some specific effect on your application, with code you can share?

Comment: @DavidMaze See update finding why VM uptime is just 1 day, seems related to VM pause. And not sure, seems narrow down the issue to hyper-v now.